# Why does (read) just set the delimiters to parentheses and then precedes the expression with a backtick?

Tags: racket

Scheme (Racket) newbie here.

I am reading this book: Programming Languages Application and Interpretation by Shriram Krishnamurthi.

I installed the plai package.

On page 7 the book talks about `(read)` and says that with this input:

```
{+ {- 3 4} 7}
```

`(read)` returns this:

```
(list `+ (list `- 3 4) 7)
```

However, when I open the command line version of Racket and type:

```
(read)
```

and then type:

```
{+ {- 3 4} 7}
```

I do not get what the book says. Instead, I get this:

```
`(+ (- 3 4) 7)
```

The `(read)` command just replaced the curly braces with parentheses and preceded the entire expression with a backtick. It didn't add `list`.

Is the book wrong? Or, is there something I need to do to get `(read)` to behave as described by the book?

Comment: Just different ways of printing the same value.

Comment: The difference is not in `read` but in the display. Open your REPL and compare `'(a b c)` to `(list 'a 'b 'c)`.

Comment: (eq? '(a b c) (list 'a 'b 'c)) returns #f

Comment: (eq? (list '+ (list '- 3 4) 7) '(+ (- 3 4) 7)) returns #f  So they are not the same, right?

Comment: You need `equal?` to compare lists. `eq?` on lists/pairs would only return true if they're both empty lists or both the same cons cell object.

Comment: See https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Equality.html#%28part._model-eq%29

Comment: (equal? (list `+ (list `- 3 4) 7) `(+ (- 3 4) 7)) returns #t. Okay, so they are equal. Still, I like the former format better than the later format . Is there any way to tell (read) to return the result in the former format rather than the later format? Thanks for your help @Shawn!

Comment: @RogerCostello Again, the result does not depend on `read`, but on how your REPL formats lists for display. The vast majority of people prefer the shorter "quoted list" format to the longer "construction by procedure" form. (The author changed this section in the second edition – it is a bit clearer there.)

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the discussion above (and answer your final question): DrRacket has multiple ways of displaying s-expressions.

The default setting is called "print". It sounds like what you want is called "constructor" style printing.

To change this, open the "Language>Choose Language..." menu, click "Show Details" (unless details are already shown), and then change the setting in the "Output Syntax" box from "print" to "Constructor".

Comment: And if you're using the command line REPL instead of DrRacket like OP says they are?

Comment: Maybe https://docs.racket-lang.org/mzlib/mzlib_pconvert.html#%28def._%28%28lib._mzlib%2Fpconvert..rkt%29._print-convert%29%29

Comment: @Shawn ouch good point, my bad. In this case it depends on exactly how OP is using the command-line. Are they using it interactively, or just to load & run a compiled racket file?